# Is there a LINQ function for getting the longest string in a list of strings?

Tags: c#, string, linq

Is there a `LINQ` function for this is or would one have to code it themselves like this:

```
static string GetLongestStringInList()
{
    string longest = list[0];

    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (s.Length > longest.Length)
        {
            longest = s;
        }
    }

    return longest;
}
```

Comment: What result do you like if there are two strings that shares the longest lenght?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This will do it with only one loop iteration:

```
list.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);
```

Comment: This answer is by far the fastest.  I wrote a small test for 1 million strings, each between 1-2000 characters.  @Dani's answer's speed was `3.26 seconds` and your answer was `0.36 seconds`.  This was an average of 15 runs for each method.  I'd forgotten all about the Aggregate extension method! :)

Comment: The `Aggregate` function is so simple, yet it uniquely solves so many interesting problems!

Comment: It's also called `reduce` or `fold` in other languages (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

Comment: All the answers which use OrderBy are performing a sort, an O(nlogn) operation. Finding the maximum entry in a sequence should be a O(n) operation.

Comment: Spectacular! But do we really need the empty string as a starting value there? This works too: var longest = list.Aggregate((max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere on this page, since 2021, there is `list.MaxBy(x => x.Length)` in Linq (.NET, but not .NET Framework), see [`MaxBy` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby).

Answer (score 41):

You can use this: `list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();`

Comment: You could even use `FirstOrDefault` in case array is empty to avoid an error.

Comment: @joshua Wouldn't `FirstOrDefault` give wrong result if the array is empty? It would return the default but we would expect null if array is empty. I also heard that `FirstOrDefault` should be avoided due to performance overheads

Comment: @Suhas I haven't heard anything on performance, so I won't comment on that. As for using it - it'll depend on the context in which it is used. If you called `First` on a `string[] list = new string[0];` linq will throw an exception where `FirstOrDefault` will return null without throwing an exception. I generally find myself using `FirstOrDefault` and checking the result sometime after the call. If you're in a situation where you can guarantee the list *always* has at least one item, `First` is ok, but if you ever have a doubt (like selecting attributes in XML) then I use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Dani I do not recollect exactly but I believe I heard that in some podcast.

Comment: @Suhas Perhaps you were thinking of `Single` vs `First`, the difference being that `Single` always checks all items and `First` short-circuits on the first item.  But the only important difference between `First` and `FirstOrDefault` is the functionality.

Comment: If we're going to talk about performance, the real performance penalty of this technique is that the list is being sorted.  I think you'll end up paying O(nlgn) as soon as the search runs (i.e., when `First()` is called).  SimonC's solution, on the other hand, is O(n).

Answer (score 11):

```
var list = new List<string>(); // or string[] or any

list.Add("a");
list.Add("ccc");
list.Add("bb");
list.Add("eeeee");
list.Add("dddd");

// max-length
var length = list.Max(s => s.Length);

// biggest one
var biggest = list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Length == length);

// if there is more that one by equal length
var biggestList = list.Where(s => s.Length == length);

// by ordering list
var biggest = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();

// biggest-list by LINQ
var bigList2 = from s in list where s.Length == list.Max(a => a.Length) select s;

// biggest by LINQ
var biggest2 = bigList2.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

The method you want is typically called "MaxBy" and it is unfortunately not included in the standard set of sequence operators. Fortunately it is very easy to write yourself. See this answer for an implementation:

[Linq group by with a sub query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976808/linq-group-by-with-a-sub-query/976849#976849)

Comment: That implementation of `MaxBy` looks broken.  The `func` argument was never used.  I've proposed an edit of the answer to what I think it's intending to do (i.e. use `func` to select the value being compared).

Comment: @SimonC: Apparently it is easy to write incorrectly yourself too. I didn't bother to actually read the code I linked to. Good catch!

Comment: It is completely bizarre that *3* versions of .NET have come and gone without having a MaxBy/MinBy added to LINQ. I have seen production code by an "experienced" developer who wrote list.OrderBy(n => n.someValue).Last(). An O(nlogn + n) operation when O(n) is possible!

Comment: Since 2021, [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby) is a part of Linq (from .NET 6 and onwards).

Answer (score 2):

I thought there was a better way to get the longest string in a list of strings using the lambda expressions. One such way is as below.

```
string longestString = list.Max(arr => arr);
```

Hope this works good for the answer seekers.

Comment: This is wrong! `List<string> t = new() { "not", "long" }; t.Max(x => x);` returns "not"

Comment: @Justas, Only if the current culture is such that `"long"` is earlier in the alphabetical collation than is `"not"`, but that happens for typical cultures. We can certainly agree the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get the longest string in list of object/string try this:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("HELLO");
list.Add("HELLO WORLD");
String maxString = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First();
```

The variable `maxString` will contain the value `"HELLO WORLD"`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `MaxBy`, available since .Net6:

`string longestString = list.MaxBy(x => x.Length);`

Answer (score -1):

Add a ThenBy() to guarantee a return order if there are multiple strings with the same length

```
var longest = list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
                   .ThenBy(s => s)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```