# Deserializing a stream of JSON Output

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am using an API that provides the output in JSON format and I am sure about the fields that it contains. I want to deserialize it into a list  format.
I went through the Newtonsoft.Json namespace but didn't get much help. The following article was good but it didn't serve my purpose as I am not aware of the key/value pairs.
Article: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

My code:

```
static void GetShares()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://shares.ppe.datatransfer.microsoft.com/api/v1/data/shares/");

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic "+
    Convert.ToBase64String(
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("useridandpassword")));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
}
```

Comment: *"I want to deserialize it into a readable format."* - JSON is already in a human-readable format, because it is "just" a string. Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your desired output format. What language are you trying to use, JavaScript or C#?

Comment: By readable format i mean in the from of a list i.e all the keys in one column and the corresponding values in the other.

Comment: @dotnetman You don't need to put "Edit 1" in your title when you edit your post.  Each post has an [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41009904/revisions) which shows that it was edited and what was changed.  Everyone can see the edit history on any post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://shares.ppe.datatransfer.microsoft.com/api/v1/data/shares/");

request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " +
Convert.ToBase64String(
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("userid:password")));
request.ContentType = "application/json";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

JArray items = JArray.Parse(responseFromServer);

Console.WriteLine($"{"Keys".PadRight(24)}Values");
Console.WriteLine($"{"".PadRight(50, '-')}");

foreach (JToken token in items)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = token.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    int length = 28;

    foreach (var property in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{property.Key.PadRight(length)}{property.Value}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"----------------------");
}
```

This parses the payload as a `JArray`, grabs the first item (check for `null` first), deserialises it into a dictionary and selects the keys. I picked 24 as it's the longest key length. You could make the padding variable by using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975983/203093).

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code and it seems that it is returning and printing the following data on console(not in readable format(indented)).

```
[
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-06-09T17:23:53-07:00",
    "directory": "/",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 63,
    "name": "linuxServerRoot",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:26-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:26-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 6,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-10-17T14:52:06-07:00",
    "directory": "/Windows_RTM",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 584,
    "name": "Windows_RTM1.1",
    "node_id": 7,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:33-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:33-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 3,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T00:40:20-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription--Default no stats",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1401,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription--Default no stats",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:27-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:27-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T01:06:20-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription-EyeBall",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1408,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription-EyeBall",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:28-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:28-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T01:06:50-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription-Goku",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1409,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription-Goku",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:29-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:29-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T01:07:18-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription-Cybersecurity",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1410,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription-Cybersecurity",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:30-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:30-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T01:08:00-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription-Feature_Phones_Dubai SOR",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1411,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription-Feature_Phones_Dubai SOR",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:31-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:31-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-29T01:10:47-08:00",
    "directory": "/Stats_subscription-For-Demo-Do not delete/WUS-Stats_subscription-Nimbus",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1412,
    "name": "WUS-Stats_subscription-Nimbus",
    "node_id": 5,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:32-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:32-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  },
  {
    "browse_count": 0,
    "bytes_free_string": null,
    "bytes_total_string": null,
    "bytes_unknown": true,
    "comment_added_at": null,
    "content_added_at": null,
    "created_at": "2016-11-30T15:49:52-08:00",
    "directory": "/EPRS-Connect/HK-EPRS-NVIDIA",
    "error_bytes_free_size": null,
    "error_percent_free": null,
    "home_share": false,
    "id": 1467,
    "name": "HK-EPRS-NVIDIA",
    "node_id": 7,
    "percent_free": null,
    "status": null,
    "status_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:34-08:00",
    "status_message": null,
    "updated_at": "2016-12-06T21:24:34-08:00",
    "warn_bytes_free_size": null,
    "warn_percent_free": null
  }
]
```

And You asked `to deserialize it in readable format.` From this statement i think you want to print/show it on the console in readable format.

To achieve this you can make use of `Newtonsoft.Json`library all you have to add the `Json.NET` nuget package to your project and following code just before the `Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);` statement.

```
JToken jsonToken = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
responseFromServer = jsonToken.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

This will print / show the JSON on console window in readable format.

Comment: Hi Vedant...which code did you execute? the one provided by me or hsimah?

Comment: @dotnetman the one provided by you. the output which i have shown in answer (the JSON) is not in readable format.

Comment: @dotnetman you just have to add the **Json.Net** nuget package into your project and two line of code before you printing out to the console which will convert un-formatted json into readable(formatted) json.