# how can print big string from a string array or get its index

Tags: java, c#, .net, arrays

I want to do a function that takes array of strings and print the big string and the num of chars, for example

```
String[] names = { "Microsoft", "lg", "apple","Samsung"}
```

the output is:

> bigger name is :Microsoft
>
> num of chars 9

I have done num of chars but i don't know how to print the name**

```
String[] names = { "microsoft", "lg", "apple","samsung"};
int big = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
    if (big<names[i].Length) {
        big = names[i].Length;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("bigger name is{0}chars  ",big);
```

Comment: introduce a second variable storing the index  of _or_ the max value, like you do with ```big```

Comment: What language: Java or C#

Comment: If you have written this code it should be trivial to understand that you need another variable that keeps the index of the array when you find the lengthest string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
String[] names = { "microsoft", "lg", "apple", "samsung" };

string longestName = names.OrderByDescending(n => n.Length).FirstOrDefault();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(longestName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Longest name is {0} ({1} chars).", longestName, longestName.Length);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

There is also a more efficient way, see [Is there a LINQ function for getting the longest string in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975935/is-there-a-linq-function-for-getting-the-longest-string-in-a-list-of-strings#7975983)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the length in `big`, store the biggest string:

```
String biggerString = "";
```

And compare the biggerString length inside the loop.